# Quillen pair with derived equivalence $\implies$ Quillen equivalence

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, derived-functors

Let $L\dashv R$ a Quillen pairs an adjunction between model categories $M,M'$ with $L$ preserving cofibrations and $R$ fibrations. From then we can construct an adjunction $\mathbb LL\dashv \mathbb RR$ between the total derived functors. Now suppose it's actually an equivalence. We want to show that $L\dashv R$ is an Quillen equivalence, that is for $x\in M$ cofibrant, $x'\in M'$ fibrant and $f\in M'(L(x),x')$ we have : $f\in WE'\iff f^{\#}\in WE$ ($f^{\#}$ is obtained via the adjunction).

My question is : how do we show this ?

Suppose for instance $f$ is a weak equivalence, we write $\eta :Id_M\to R\circ L$, $\epsilon:L\circ R\to Id_{M'}$ the natural transformations we get $f^{\#}=R(f)\circ \eta_x$ so by the 2-out-3 it's enough to show that $R(f),\eta_x\in WE$ but I don't go anywhere. I also don't know how to use the equivalence $\mathbb LL\dashv \mathbb RR$

Comment: See Prop 2.3 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Quillen+equivalence

Comment: @AlexeyDo So here we want to show that the equivalence $\mathbb LL\dashv \mathbb RR$ imply the conditions of the proposition ? What do you think of the reasoning : we consider $f:L(x)\to x'\in WE'$, we have $\gamma'(f)\in\operatorname{HoM}(\mathbb LL(x),x')\cong \operatorname{HoM'}(x,\mathbb RR(x'))$. We have that the image would be $\gamma(f^{\#})$ (I hope) and since $\gamma'(f)$ is an iso, $\gamma(f^{\#})$ is also an iso and so $f^{\#}\in WE$. I don't use the equivalence, which is suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Proposition 1.3.13 in [Hovey’s Model Category](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf).